# How do we see virtual images?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

[image]

Here in the diagram rays coming from B' point falls on two different places on retina of eye.So we should see B' at two different places. But it doesn't happen like that in reality. Is my logic wrong? where have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 9):

Your picture of the eye is incomplete.

You need to add the retina and to consider
the effect of the lens.
The lens refracts the rays coming from
the virtual object $B'$ so that they
actually arrive at the same point of the retina.

[image: eye with lens and retina]

Answer (score 6):

The two rays which are drawn entering the eye are refracted by the cornea/lens system and form a **real** image on the retina of the eye. 
It is the real image which is formed on the retina which you detect and then surmise that it came from an “object” located at $B’$ which we call a virtual image.

Put another way the eye focuses the two diverging rays on the retina.
The eye has no way of telling as to whether those two diverging rays came from a real object at $B’$ or as a result of light reflected from the mirror.
You know from your diagram know that the object $B’$ is not real.

Comment: like you said, the eye has no way of telling if the rays came from a real object as $B'$ or as a result of reflection. Our brain assumes that it is a real object at $B'$ and that is what we see. That is the reason we see refections and bending of pencils in water, because our brain assumes that light travels in a straight line, and traces these rays backward. However, what about a camera ? If we put a pencil in a glass of water, it appears to bend. If we take a photo of this, in the photo, the pencil will still appear to bend. Why is this ?

Comment: In case of our brain, we don't know if the light came from a  real object or from reflection. However, our brain assumes light comes in a straight line from an object, and so we perceive the virtual image as a real object. In case of the camera, it isn't conscious. However, the camera also 'seems to believe' that the light came from a real object at $B'$.  In a sense, how does a camera form a real image of a virtual object ?

Comment: @RayPalmer The camera does not “believe” anything rather the lens(es) refract the incoming rays (which when back produced intersect in a region which we call the virtual object) onto the retina where the rays intersect to form what we call a real image.

Answer (score 2):

If the example reflector were a flat mirror, one image of your nose is behind the mirror surface
(and if the mirror were on a wall, that'd put that image inside the wall).   Another
image of your nose is... your nose.   You can see both, but the mirror image
is virtual (because the light from that image does NOT pass through the position
inside the wall where the image is).   The actual object, your nose, is
not a mere 'image', but is a real image.   Light from the nose actually
does come from the position of the nose.

The rays from the object are shown falling on the lens of the eye, which
focuses them (so they fall at or near one point on the retina, behind the lens).

The appearance of a "B" where it would be natural to expect a nose, suggests that
one is in danger of being stung...